# Refer to .CSV for filenames, then Locate and Delete Files Recursively

Tags: csv, powershell, subdirectory

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which refers to a CSV file for a list of banned file names (mostly games) and removes them from my users' home folders. I've got it working in the root or target directory, but cannot seem to make it recursive, so that it drills-down through subfolders, despite trying to utilise the `-recurse` parameter.

As you'll see, I'm not much of a coder, but am trying to learn and better myself. My PS script looks like this:

```
cd "C:\Test user"
Import-Csv "C:\Games.csv" | foreach {Remove-Item $_.Game -Verbose -Recurse}
```

and my CSV file looks like this:

```
Game,Game1.swf,Game2.swf,Game3.swf
```

Any advice as to what I am missing in order to make this work recursively would be hugely appreciated. Thank you all in advance for being so generous with your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the structure of CSVs. Essentially CSV is a way to store tabular data (data organized in rows and columns). Your file would have to have the following structure if you want it to work with the code you posted:

```
Game
Game1.swf
Game2.swf
Game3.swf
```

The data you posted is just a comma-separated list of values. To process this string you need something like this:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Games.csv") -split ',' | Remove-Item -Verbose -Recurse
```

or perhaps like this (if you want to skip the first element):

```
(Get-Content "C:\Games.csv") -split ',' |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  Remove-Item -Verbose -Recurse
```

---

**Edit:** If you need to recursively search a folder tree for files from your CSV and then delete just the files you'd do it like this:

```
$root = 'C:\root\folder'

$items = (Get-Content "C:\Games.csv") -split ',' | Select-Object -Skip 1

Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Object { $items -contains $_.Name } |
  Remove-Item -Verbose
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar for your time and advice. I have tried both methods, amending my CSV appropriately, and both work equally well in the root directory. However, files are still not removed from sub-directories . I understand that the -Recurse parameter should allow this, but it just doesn't seem to work for me! If you have any further thoughts or advice, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: @user3638253 What are the items listed in your file? Are they files or folders? Are they listed with the full path or just the name? What is the working directory when you run the script?

Comment: Thank you. The items listed in the CSV are all file names, and are listed without paths, as I was hoping the script would work down all paths from the working directory, which is currently "C:\Test Doc Store\Test User1". Do you think I need to add a wildcard element into the CSV to force the script to interrogate all child items...?

Comment: @user3638253 That depends on what your directory structure looks like and which parts of it you actually want deleted. Usually the best approach is to put the full path to the files/folders you want to delete into the CSV.

Comment: OK, thanks again. My directory structure takes the form of a root directory, containing a home folder for each of my users. Within each users' home folder is their Documents, Pictures, Favourites folders etc. I don't know the exact path of each of the offending files, which is why I need the script to interrogate the entire structure to find and delete them. Can this be achieved with a wildcard method? Again, greatly appreciate your time and advice.